# What is a "function returning type" in C?

Tags: c, functions

C11 standard says

> 6.3.2.1  Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> A function  designator is  an  expression  that  has  function  type.
> Except  when  it  is  the operand of the sizeof operator, 65) or the
> unary & operator, a function designator with type  ‘‘**function
> returning type**’’  is converted  to  an  expression  that  has  type
> ‘‘pointer  to **function returning type**’’.

What is a "function  returning type"? Is it the same as a function type?

Thanks.

Comment: From the [discussion](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.2.1.pdf) it looks like it just means a function pointer. Hense, the italicized `type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording of a "function returning *type*" just means a function defined as returning some type `T`, such as  `T f() {  .... }`.

The quoted clause just tells you that using the designator of the function, for example its name `f`, in an expression, would have the type "pointer to a function returning T".  To be read with the following associative priorities:  "pointer to " "a function returning T".

The wording avoids to say the name of the function,  since the rule is anything that designates a function, including a dereferenced function pointer.

Example, with T being `void`:

```
void f(){ printf("Oops\n");}

int main(void) {
    void (*pf1)(), (*pf2)(); 
    void (*a[3])();  

    pf2 = &f;   // &f is the address of f, so a pointer to a function returning void
    pf1 = f;    // f is a function designator,  it's converted to a function pointer
    a[0]=f;     // same, but for the fun it's stored in an array of function pointers
    printf ("%lx %lx %lx %lx %lx\n", f, &f,  pf1, pf2, a[0]);  // all the same
    pf2();      // will call the function as well.  pf2 is already a function pointer
    
    (*pf1)();     // here we see that *pf1 is also a function designator
    pf2 = *pf1;   // *pf1 is converted to a function pointer, so it's pf1   
    printf ("%lx %lx\n", pf1, pf2);    // all the same 

    (***************pf1)(); // Sorry: I couldn't resist ;-)

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are functions returning void, functions returning int, functions returning double, and so on. To speak about all those functions, you call them “functions returning type”.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the phrase means only the return type of a function

Comment: Exactly. It's not about the type of a function's return value, it's about the type of the function.

Comment: @Tim - in the standard, the word "type" is typographically distinguished, to indicate that it's meant as a placeholder, e.g., it's written like this: "array of *type*" (meaning array of T) , and "function returning *type*" (meaning function with the return type T). It's not a phrase, it's a phrase template, if you will; perhaps another way to express it would be: "converted to an expression that has type: pointer to function returning <type>".